# dynamic cast not working for non polymorphic base class?

Tags: c++, casting

Here the second cast gives an error saying

`cast.cc:35:35: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘base’ (of type ‘class CBase*’) to type ‘class CDerived*’ (source type is not polymorphic)`

```
    CBase * base = new CDerived; 
    CBase* pb;
    CDerived * der = new CDerived; 
    CDerived* pd;
    pb = dynamic_cast<CBase*>(der);     // ok: derived-to-base
    pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(base);  // wrong: base-to-derived
```

What is meannt by this ??

And why this works if I make the base class polymorphic ?

Can some one please let me know the basic concept behind this.

Answer (score 5):

Because the standard says so (see the section [expr.dynamic.cast] in the C++ standard):

> ... `dynamic_cast<T>(v)`
>
> ... `v` shall be a pointer to or an lvalue of a polymorphic type

In practice, because the [run-time type information (RTTI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTTI) required to make dynamic down-casts (i.e. from base to derived) possible are generated along with the [vtbl/vptr mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTBL), which isn't required if there are no polymorphic member functions.

Up-casts (i.e. derived to base), on the other hand, require no RTTI (there's no run-time decision to be made).  Quoting from the same section of the standard:

> ```
> struct B { };
> struct D : B { };
> void foo(D* dp) {
>     B* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(dp); // equivalent to B* bp = dp;
> }
> ```

Comment: Does the compiler substitute a static_cast for the dynamic_cast when it knows it's a derived-to-base conversion? That's what you're implying, right?

Comment: @MarkRansom: I guess that's what I'm implying, but I'm not going to make it explicit, in case it's wrong!