# How to downcast from non-polymorphic virtual base class?

Tags: c++, downcast, virtual-inheritance

Is there a way to downcast from a virtual base class to a derived class when there are no virtual functions involved? Here's some code to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

```
struct Base1
{
  int data;
};

struct Base2
{
  char odd_size[9];
};

struct ViBase
{
  double value;
};


struct MostDerived : Base1, Base2, virtual ViBase
{
  bool ok;
};


void foo(ViBase &v)
{
  MostDerived &md = somehow_cast<MostDerived&>(v);  //but HOW?
  md.ok = true;
}


int main()
{
  MostDerived md;
  foo(md);
}
```

Please note that the code is for demonstration only. My real scenario is fairly complex and involves template parameters and casting from one to another, knowing only that the first one is a base of the second one; it can be a normal or virtual base and it may or may not have virtual functions. (See simplified example at the bottom). I can detect the polymorphic case and the virtual/non-virtual base case using type traits, and solve all of them except the non-polymorphic virtual base. So that's what I'm asking about.

I can't really think of a way to do the cast:

- Implicit conversions are right out; these only do upcasts.
- `static_cast` is explicitly forbidden for casting from a virtual base class:

  > **5.2.9/2** ... and `B` is neither a virtual base class of `D` nor a base class of a virtual base class of `D`. ...
- `dynamic_cast` can't do it either, as downcasts require a polymorphic class

  > **5.2.7/6** Otherwise, `v` shall be a pointer to or a glvalue of a polymorphic type (10.3).
  >
  > **10.3/1** ... A class that declares or inherits a virtual function is called a *polymorphic class.*
- `reinterpret_cast` doesn't apply here at all.

If `MostDerived` had at least one virtual function, this could of course be solved with `dynamic_cast`. But when it does not, is there a way to do the cast?

<sup>(NOTE All quotes are taken from C++11 draft N3485)</sup>

---

In light of comments focusing on the above example code too much, here's a sketch of what my real situation is:

```
template <class T_MostDerived>
struct Bar
{
  template <class T_Base>
  void foo(T_Base &b, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T_Base, T_MostDerived>::value>::type * = nullptr)
  {
    T_MostDerived &md = somehow_cast<T_MostDerived>(b);
    do_stuff_with(md);
  }
};
```

That is, I know that `T_Base` is a base class of `T_MostDerived` (and I know that `T_MostDerived` is really the most derived type), but I don't know anything else about them; `Bar` is my code, part of a library, which unknown clients can use. I can *detect* that it's a non-polymorphic virtual base, but I can't *cast* it in such case.

Comment: Why exactly can't you make `ViBase` polymorphic? (e.g., you could make its destructor virtual)

Comment: If ViBase is not polymorphic, why use it as a virtual base class?

Comment: Remove the `virtual` keyword. Then reinterpret happily the references/pointers as you are now dealing with plain structs...

Comment: As long `Base1` and `Base2` are unrelated to `ViBase`, which effect should the `virtual` inheritance take here?

Comment: @Niall I think it doesn't necessarily to be polymorphic to be used with `virtual` inheritance. That should only guarantee it's initialized once, if found multiple times in the `MostDerived`'s inheritance tree, as far as I understood the feature so far.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've edited the question a bit - the code is only to demonstrate what exactly I'm talking about. In my real situation, the classes are outside my control.

Comment: @Angew From my interpretation, `virtual` will guarantee you'll get an unambiguously resolved _'instance'_ of your base class if using a `dynamic_cast<ViBase*>(this)` (where this refers to `MostDerived`).

Comment: I'm reading from n3797, 5.2.7/2, If T is an lvalue reference type, v shall be an lvalue of a complete class type,and the result is an lvalue of the type referred to by T. I think this applies here, so I would think dynamic_cast is what you need.

Comment: @Niall Unfortunately, point 5 of that section solves upcasts only, and then point 6 says "otherwise, `v` shall be polymorphic" (exact quote is in the question).

Comment: @Angew: thanks for teaching me something new today also. each day I learn something a new I can rejoice that I'm still a thinking being.

Comment: I think you may be out of luck, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10524622/3747990. Frankly though, I think you should be able to do what you want to do. Consider approaching the committee on this.

Comment: In your sketch of your actual problem, are you the one that define `T_MostDerived`, or is that still framework stuff you don't own? Also, I am assuming you are in full control over the implementation of `foo()`?

Comment: @jxh Yes, I am in full control of `foo()`, but that's about it. What I am writing is a library, so `Bar` is the end product given away to unknown clients who can instantiate it with anything they wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>There is an implicit unambigious conversion from `MostDerived&` to its `ViBase&`. A `static_cast` can express such a conversion explicitly, and can also do the opposite conversion. That’s the kinds of conversions that `static_cast` does.</del>

As the OP noted a `static_cast` down from virtual base is invalid.

The source code below illustrates why:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct B { virtual ~B(){} };
struct D: virtual B {};
struct E: virtual B {};
struct X: D, E {};

auto main() -> int
{
    X   x;
    B&  b = static_cast<E&>( x );

    // Can't do the following for the address adjustment that would work for
    // D sub-object won't work for E sub-object, yet declarations of D and E
    // are identical -- so the address adjustment can't be inferred from that.
    //
    //static_cast<D&>( b );

    // This is OK:
    dynamic_cast<D&>( b );
}
```

Essentially, as this shows, you can't infer the address adjustment from the declaration of `D` (or `E`) alone. And neither can the compiler. This also rules out `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: True (and +1), but it's more of an observation. Shall I read the answer as "there is no way?" Perhaps you could state it more explicitly?

Comment: @Angew: Since we have exhausted all means of casting with well-defined effect down from non-polymorphic virtual base class, there is no such. That doesn't mean "no way", but it means that whatever you do will have some cost, e.g. portability (for formally UB code) or complexity and memory footprint (for dynamically registering all `Base` objects), or efficiency (for scanning for known pattern). I think the main issue to focus on is that a non-polymorphic virtual base class as the statically known type, indicates a design-level failure to retain proper type. As I see it.

Answer (score 2):

This requires a hack. A downcast requires math since multiple inheritance may put the base class in some arbitrary position within the derived class. However, if you know the base class is virtually inherited, then there should only be one instance of it in the derived class. This means you can create a conversion function:

```
struct MostDerived : Base1, Base2, virtual ViBase
{
  bool ok;
  template <typename T> static MostDerived * somehow_cast (T *v) {
    static MostDerived derived;
    static T &from = derived;
    static size_t delta
      = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&from) - reinterpret_cast<char *>(&derived);
    char *to = reinterpret_cast<char *>(v);
    return reinterpret_cast<MostDerived *>(to - delta);
  }
};
```

What the special C++ casts give you that this function does not is type safety. This function blindly assumes that the passed in `ViBase` has an appropriate derived child to cast into, which is generally not the case.

Comment: A constraint here is that it must be known that the `*v` object's most derived object is really a `MostDerived` and not a class derived from `MostDerived`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf +1, true in general. Fortunately, in my real case, I will know that for certain.

Comment: +1; that's exactly what I plan to do. Unfortunately, it's technically undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you want to avoid undefined behavior, you will need to create a lookup table that maps from `ViBase` to `MostDerived` for you.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the need for MostDerived to be default-constructible? And how exactly would a lookup table avoid UB? Wouldn't you still need to invoke UB when populating the table?

Comment: @celticminstrel C uses a similar kind of computation for `offsetof()`, and it uses NULL pointer cast to the containing (`MostDerived`) structure. I was uncomfortable presenting that, since a compiler is allowed to do funny math with NULL, but regular code is not really supposed to.

Comment: @celticminstrel A lookup table would be populated at the time the `MostDerived` was instantiated. So, there would not be any UB. So if you had `unordered_map<Base1 *, MostDerived *>`, then it would be populated from the `MostDerived` constructor like: `map[this] = this;`