# Can size of pointers to non-union classes differ?

Tags: c++, pointers, sizeof, language-lawyer

I understand there are HW platforms where you need more information to point to a `char` than you need to point to an `int` (the platform having non-addressable bytes, so a pointer to `char` needs to store a pointer to a word and also an index of a byte in the word). So it is possible that `sizeof(int*) < sizeof(char*)` on such platforms.

Can something similar happen with pointers to non-union classes? C++ allows covariant returns types on virtual functions. Let's say we have classes like this:

```
struct Gadget
{
  // some content
};


struct Widget
{
  virtual Gadget* getGadget();
};
```

Any code which calls `getGadget()` has to work when receiving a `Gadget*`, but the same code (actually the same *compiled binary* code) has to work when it receives a pointer to a type derived from `Gadget` as well (perhaps one which is defined in a totally different library). The only way I can reasonably see this happening is `sizeof(T*) == sizeof(U*)` for all non-union class types `T` and `U`.

So my question is, given one particular *practical* compiler (that excludes hypothetical Hell++) on one particular platform, is it reasonable to expect that all pointers to non-union class types will be of the same size? Or is there a *practical* reason why a compiler might want to use different sizes while remaining compliant with covariant return types?

On platforms where different "levels" of pointer exist (such as `__near` and `__far`), assume the *same* attribute applied to both.

Comment: A side note: There are plenty of examples in the embedded world where data pointers and code pointers have different sizes.

Comment: @Lindydancer Of course. But I am explicitly asking just about data pointers, and only about a subset of them at that.

Comment: @Casey `language-lawyer` was already added and removed once. Are you sure it's applicable? After all, I am asking about practical implementations, not about a hypothetical one which would follow the letter of the standard while doing things entirely stupid in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C has a hard requirement that all pointers to all structure types have the same representation and alignment.

> **6.2.5 Types**
>
> 27 [...] All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. [...]

C++ effectively requires binary compatibility with a C implementation, because of the standard's requirements for `extern "C"`, so indirectly, this requires all pointers to structure types that are valid in C (POD types, pretty much) to have the same representation and alignment in C++ too.

No such requirement seems to have been made for non-POD types, so an implementation would be allowed to use different pointer sizes in that case. You suggest that that cannot work, but to follow your example,

```
struct G { };
struct H : G { };

struct W
{
  virtual G* f() { ... }
};
struct X : W
{
  virtual H* f() { ... }
};
```

could be translated to (pseudo-code)

```
struct W
{
  virtual G* f() { ... }
};
struct X : W
{
  override G* f() { ... }
  inline H* __X_f() { return static_cast<H *>(f()); }
};
```

which would still match the requirements of the language.

A valid reason why two pointers to structure types might not be identical is when a C++ compiler would be ported to a platform that has an existing C compiler with a poorly-designed ABI. `G` is a POD type, so `G *` needs to be exactly what it is in C. `H` is not a POD type, so `H *` does not need to match any C type.

For alignment, that can actually happen: something that really happened is that the x86-32 ABI on a typical GNU/Linux system requires 64-bit integer types to be 32-bit aligned, even though the processor's preferred alignment is actually 64-bit. Now comes another implementer, and they decide that they do want to require 64-bit alignment, but are stuck if they want to remain compatible with the existing implementation.

For sizes, I cannot think of a reasonable scenario in which it would happen, but I am unsure whether that might be a lack of imagination on my part.

Comment: Do you think an implementation of such a trick would be possible even if `G` is a non-polymorphic virtual base class of `H` and thus [the `static_cast` (or any other cast) is not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24920749/1782465)?

Comment: @Angew Good question. Yes, such a trick would still be possible, it would simply have to be done the other way around: the pseudo-code would be `override G* f() final { return __X_f(); } virtual H* __X_f() { ... }`, and the compiler would have to ensure that further overrides of `f` actually end up overrides of `__X_f`.

Comment: @Angew Actually, thinking about it, compilers already need to do that, and do in fact already do that, whenever a `derived *` cannot simply be re-interpreted as a `base *` (including in your example).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand C and C++ assume memory to be linearly byte addressable. Certain platforms (early ARM) however insist on word aligned loads and stores. In such a case, it is the compiler's responsibility to round the pointer to the word boundary and then perform the necessary bit shift operations when fetching say a char.

But since this is all done only on loads and stores, all pointers still all look the same.