# When is a pointer-to-array convertible to a pointer-to-array of different type?

Tags: c++, c++17

I was checking out the [cppreference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) for `std::unique_ptr` and noticed that C++17 seems to have made some interesting changes. In particular, the specialization for `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` now accepts template arguments where it previously only accepted `std::unique_ptr::pointer` arguments. For example, here is a declaration for one of the `reset` member functions of `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`:

```
template <typename U> void reset(U p);
```

The site states that:

> Behaves the same as the `reset` member of the primary template, except that it will only participate in overload resolution if either
>   `U` is the same type as `pointer`, or
>   `pointer` is the same type as `element_type*` and `U` is a pointer type `V*` such that `V(*)[]` is convertible to `element_type(*)[]`.

I'm assuming that this was done for safety - you wouldn't want to perform `delete[]` on a pointer to an array of derived type that was assigned to a pointer to its base type (prior to C++17 this was marked as deleted). As expected, this code compiles fine:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct foo {};
struct bar : public foo {};
static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<bar(*)[], foo(*)[]>);
```

What's interesting, however, is that the following does *not* compile, failing both `static_assert`s:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct foo {};
struct bar : public foo {};
static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<bar*(*)[], foo*(*)[]>);
static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<std::unique_ptr<bar>(*)[], std::unique_ptr<foo>(*)[]>);
```

Why is that? In what scenario will this overload be used?

Comment: In hindsight, I guess that the array of `unique_ptr` example is pretty obvious, but I'm still genuinely curious about this

Comment: Why do you expect `bar*(*)[]` to be convertible to `foo*(*)[]` exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basically a way of saying "you can pass a less const-y pointer if it's safe to do so", e.g., `int* p = /*...*/; unique_ptr<const int []> up; up.reset(p);`

For different types `U` and `V`, the only case where `U(*)[]` is (implicitly) convertible to `V(*)[]` is by a [qualification conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.qual), i.e., when you are adding `const`/`volatile` at the right places in the type. The exact rules are complicated (because they handle arbitrarily nested pointers/pointer-to-members/arrays; click the link if you want to know), but they essentially allow conversion only when it's safe; the specification of `unique_ptr` then leverages that fact so that it doesn't have to redefine "safe", at the cost of making the intent a little more cryptic.

Comment: Ahh, makes perfect sense. I totally overlooked const conversion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
struct foo {};
struct bar : public foo {};
```

In this trivial case, it's quite likely that the value representation of a `foo*` is exactly the same as that of a `bar*`, so it *could* be possible to convert between arrays of them. However, as soon as `bar` gets more complex, it no longer holds. Consider this:

```
struct foo {};
struct qux {};
struct bar : qux, foo {};
```

Now, a `bar*` is implicitly convertible to a `foo*`, but that conversion does not keep its exact value: it requires an offset from `qux` to `foo`.

Likewise, as soon as virtuals, multiple access control levels, etc. enter the picture, the address of the base class subobject can become different from that of the most derived object. Such pointers can even be of different size<sup>(1)</sup>.

This is why there is only a limited set of cases where a `derived*` can be used as a `base*` without a value-changing conversion. My guess is that making allowances for the limited case would complicate the standard for little benefit, so conversions between such pointer arrays are simply disallowed.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> It's a bit of an obscure case, but it could happen if the C++ compiler was constrained by a poorly designed C ABI. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25525214/1782465) discusses such a situation.